# mongoDB how to compare 2 fields in same document with unknown field names

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have collection like below which maintains history of modifications done i.e. it maintains old and new value of modified sub doc.

Example: If only name was modified in basic sub doc, whole of basic doc will be placed in old section.

I want to check what all fields were modified and print it, without knowing all the field names in old section.

Example : Is "basic.name" equal to "transactionDetails.old.basic.name", if false, print it.

But I am not certain if "transactionDetails.old.basic.name" is present or not.

My requirement:
1) Whats the first field in "transactionDetails.old"
2) Check if it is equal to New field value, if false, print it.
3) Repeat above for next field in "transactionDetails.old" doc

```
db.collection.findOne()
{
    "basic": {
        "name": "newName",
        "companyName": "NewCompany",
        "address": "NewAddress"
    },
    "official": {
        //New official stuff
    },
    "transactionDetails": {
        "old": {
            "basic": {
                "name": "OldName",
                "companyName": "OldCompany",
                "address": "OldAddress"
            },
            "official": {
                //Old official stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
collection.aggregate({
    $project: {
        "old": "$transactionDetails.old", // store everything in "transcationDetails.old" in the "old" field
        "new": "$$ROOT", // store the entire document in the "new field"
        "_id": 0 // get rid of "_id" field
    }
}, {
    // ugly hack which won't do anything really because of what seems like a bug in a MongoDB bug (UPDATE: I tried to test that again, couldn't reproduce the error, though, and I cannot remember which version I was running on back then. So you might well want to try the query without this stage...):
    // without this (or any other probably) stage here, I guess,
    // MongoDB attempts to combine the two project stages but returns the wrong document...
    $sort: {
       "whatever": 1
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "new._id": 0, // get rid of inner "_id" field
        "new.transactionDetails": 0 // get rid of inner "transactionDetails" field
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "newArray": { $objectToArray: "$new" }, // transform "new" field into array of key-value pairs
        "oldArray": { $objectToArray: "$old" }, // do the same for "old"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "difference": {
            $arrayToObject: { // transform array of key-value pairs back to document
                $filter: {                               // run a filter...
                    input: "$oldArray",                  // ...on the "oldArray" field...
                    cond: {                              // ...which will throw out all items...
                        $not: [{                         // ...that do not...
                            $in: [ "this", "$newArray" ] // ...also appear identically in the "newArray" field
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort spent on this, I will check if this can be implemented

Comment: Unfortunately I will not be able to use $objectToArray as it is not supported in MongoDB 3.2.11, is there any other way?

Comment: I don't think there is, unfortunately... Upgrading is not an option?